# Mocking endpoint response in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a camel route that sends to loadbalancer and processes the response. Is it possible to mock that response somehow in unit test? I tried to use velocity but it doesn't seem to work in unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Apache already takes care of such testing requirements. There is [adviceWith](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/advicewith.html) construct which will solve this problem.

Quoting the example directly with few modifications from the link mentioned above:

```
 @Test
 public void testAdvised() throws Exception {
     context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
         @Override public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:start").id("my-route").to("mock:foo");
         }
    });

    context.getRouteDefinition("my-route").adviceWith(context, new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
      // intercept sending to mock:foo and do something else
      interceptSendToEndpoint("mock:foo")
          .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
          .to("log:foo")
          .to("mock:result");
      }
    });

    getMockEndpoint("mock:foo").expectedMessageCount(0);
    getMockEndpoint("mock:result").expectedMessageCount(1);

    template.sendBody("direct:start", "Hello World");

    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}
```

Now here a route is defined as:
`from("direct:start").id("my-route").to("mock:foo");`

And let's say we want to mock the `to` part here.

This is precisely doing it for me:

```
context.getRouteDefinition("my-route").adviceWith(context, new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
      // intercept sending to mock:foo and do something else
      interceptSendToEndpoint("mock:foo")
          .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
          .to("log:foo")
          .to("mock:result");
      }
    });
```

We get the reference of the route definition we want to modify from CamelContext and using the adviceWith method we can define what all action needs to be done. As here, I advised not to send to actual destination i.e. `mock:foo`, rather send to two other routes `log:foo` and `mock:result`.

Hope it answers your query.

Comment: This replaces original endpoint with a mocked one. What I need is to simulate response from the original endpoint. Like in java's Mockito when().then... In my original route that response goes through a list of xstls.

Comment: Even Mockito proxies the class, and does not really execute the method, isn't your intention the same. You want to bypass the rest api call and mock the response?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to mock the response so it could be processed further

Comment: In that case, you can share your existing route definition and I can look at how we can use this.